# Why SQS.sendMessage but got the batch Records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

```
TS CODE:
  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const item = {
      MessageBody: 'string #' + i,
      QueueUrl: '......myqueue/-ping.fifo',
    }

    await sqs.sendMessage(item ).promise();
}
```

I have another lambda function to subs queue:

```
TS CODE
export const handleEvent: SQSHandler = async (event: SQSEvent) => {
  console.log('-------------------LENGTH: ' ,event.Records.length);
};
```

I expected to have len = 1

Sometime I got len > 1, another times len = 8 (records).

Can any know why I have len > 1?

Comment: Because lambda by default batches messages if possible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html Note that if you batch send messages nothing guarantees that a lambda sees batched invocations. The two are completely unrelated.

Comment: You can set the batch size to 1 if you only want one record at a time on the receiving end.